# Generate bottom scroll on a live chat using jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a trouble to generate a animation to the end of my live chat

I tried :

```
document.getElementById("chat-body").scrollTop = document.getElementById("chat-body").scrollHeight;
```

but with no result there is my html code for the chat:

```
<div id="panel" class="panel">
                <!--Widget body-->
                <div id="chat-body" class="collapse in">
                    <div class="nano has-scrollbar" id="scrollbar" style="height:380px">
                        <div class="nano-content pad-all" tabindex="0" style="right: -17px;">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled media-block">
                                <li class="mar-btm" id="conversation">

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nano-pane"><div class="nano-slider" style="height: 141px; overflow: auto"></div></div></div>

                    <!--Widget footer-->
                    <div class="panel-footer" style="background-color: transparent!important; max-height: 20%;">
                        <form id="send_message">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="youplay-input col-xs-7 col-sm-8 text-center" style="margin-left: 4%">
                                    <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3">
                                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block" type="submit">Send</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I append elements to: `<li id="conversation"></li>` and use this template : http://bootdey.com/snippets/view/messages-chat-widget

Thanks a lot for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use the **.nano-content** since it contains your ul and items:

```
var chat = $('.nano-content');
chat.scrollTop(chat.prop('scrollHeight'));
```

Or if you want to get fancy and animate the scroll:

```
chat.animate({scrollTop:chat.prop('scrollHeight')});
```

Comment: I tried this code but this is generate a scroll to top of the chat :(

Comment: It scrolls to the bottom for me. Try the animated version please.

Comment: with chat.animate({scrollTop:chat.prop('scrollHeight')}); this scroll down a little

Comment: Try a large fixed number please: chat.animate({scrollTop:2000});

Comment: For some reason the scrollHeight isn't coming back correctly for you. You might try putting a small delay between when you add messages and scroll using setTimeout

Comment: <div class="nano-pane"><div class="nano-slider" style="height: 141px; overflow: auto"></div></div></div> this gives the slider

Answer (score 0):

Solved by :

```
 var chat = $('.nano-content');
 var chatItems = $('.mar-btm').length;
 chat.animate({scrollTop: (chat.prop('scrollHeight') * chatItems)});
```

Thanks a lot @nfreeze